# need to creat share to unlock for all my posts on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, share

How to create a share to unlock for all my posts on WordPress automatically?

if any one know  answer me pleas

Comment: When asking a question you should provide code or proof of how you tried to solve the problem, your question seems to broad and vague.

Answer (score 0):

There is a well known plugin for this on Wordpress called Social Locker

https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/social-locker/